# w3wp.exe consuming more memory for sharepoint site

Tags: worker-process

w3wp.exe is consuming more memory for sharepoint site(shows in task manager)

what is the root casue of this issue ?

Please  tel me the  possible steps to resolve this issue ?

---

Comment: How much more memory, exactly?

Comment: Doesn't it stand to reason that a small asp.net site will take less memory than the whole of SharePoint?

Answer (score 5):

Are you sure this a problem?  Memory is there to be used after all.  It might be just that people are using your application.

A common cause of memory leaks is the use of SPWeb and SPSite objects that are incorrectly managed.  This usually becomes apparent by inpecting the ULS logs.  Frequent app pool recycles are also an indicator.

Check out [this article on correct disposal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee557362.aspx)

If you suspect a component, you can run [SPDisposecheck](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=spdisposecheck%202010%20download&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en-gb&client=safari) against the DLL and it will flag up any issues.

Do ensure you're not prematurely optimising. Also, memory is cheap - stick some more in, it'll save you grey hairs in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. I have reviewed my source code and find out the cause. Maybe it can help you.

My old source code

```
private void InitData()
        {
            SPWeb openWeb = null;

            if (!Utility.ContainsCurrentUser(SYS_Constant.Groups.SYS_ADMIN, SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName))
            {
                SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate
                {
                    using (var siteCollection = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.ID))
                    {
                        using (var impersonateWeb= siteCollection.OpenWeb(SPContext.Current.Web.ID))
                        {
                            openWeb = impersonateWeb;

                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            InitSapmleData(openWeb);
        }
```

And the new one

```
private void InitData()
        {
            //SPWeb openWeb = null;

            if (!Utility.ContainsCurrentUser(SYS_Constant.Groups.SYS_ADMIN, SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName))
            {
                SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate
                {
                    using (var siteCollection = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.ID))
                    {
                        using (var openWeb = siteCollection.OpenWeb(SPContext.Current.Web.ID))
                        {
                            //openWeb = impersonateWeb;
                            InitSapmleData(openWeb);
                        }// The memory is released here
                    }
                });
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

+1 with SHug, the first thing I always do in my development is to run SPDisposeCheck and fix all issues, also read SHug article on disposal, its a must on a sharepoint developer arsenal, you should learn it from heart.